# How to sort an object by its values with multiple keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

[I want to use the sort method explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) but I have

```
{
  "CYLINDER": 2986,
  "HYDRAULIC": 1421,
  "JACKS": 84,
  "INSTALLATION": 119,
  "REAR": 61,
  "JACK": 334,
  "TUBE": 1,
  "FEED": 114,
  "ASSEMBLY": 326,
  "DCS": 2,
  "TOWER": 65,
  "RAISING": 8,
  "BREAKOUT": 6,
}
```

I have created this function where I group every string together and add a count (as the value for the key, see above)

```
function generateCountDuplication(wordArray) {
  const countedWords = wordArray.reduce(function(allWords, word) {
    if (word in allWords) {
      allWords[word]++;
    }
    else {
      allWords[word] = 1;
    }
    return allWords;
  }, {});
  return countedWords;
}
```

I have tried to google and look here on Stackoverflow, but have not found any where to sort by the value **when the key is not unique**. Any clue how to solve?

I want this as a result:

```
{
  "TUBE": 1,
  "DCS": 2,
  "BREAKOUT": 6,
  "RAISING": 8,
  "REAR": 61,
  "TOWER": 65,
  "JACKS": 84,
  "FEED": 114,
  "INSTALLATION": 119,
  "ASSEMBLY": 326,
  "JACK": 334,
  "HYDRAULIC": 1421,
  "CYLINDER": 2986
}
```

Comment: don't think you can sort an object in javascript

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  You have an array of objects like that?

Comment: What are you trying to sort by? For instance, if the array contains the object you specified, plus one that's exactly the same except TUBE is 5, does your object come before mine, does my object come before yours, or do they count as being equal?

Comment: They don't in the example and if they did, then alphabetically would be my suggestion

Comment: sort()  is for arrays ..... i believe this is an object...sort() doesnt work with arrays,

Comment: `Object.keys(yourObj).sort((a,b) => yourObj[a] - yourObj[b])`

Comment: PLEASE show an example of your expected output

Comment: FINALLY a complete example. This is what I THOUGHT you meant

Comment: Very sorry for not from the beginning describing what I would like to have as an end result.

Comment: ANd just an FYI: Not all browser/js engines guarantee object order. So better off using an array and mapping values.

Comment: Relying on the order of object properties from things like `for ... in` or `Object.keys()` is a very risky practice and a fertile breeding ground for bugs. Semantically, a property is a property, and order makes no difference in how the object actually works. If you just want to do this for presentation purposes, there are simpler solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsing `Object.keys()` and `map` as follows you can achieve your expected result.

```js
const list = {
  "CYLINDER": 2986,
  "HYDRAULIC": 1421,
  "JACKS": 84,
  "INSTALLATION": 119,
  "REAR": 61,
  "JACK": 334,
  "TUBE": 1,
  "FEED": 114,
  "ASSEMBLY": 326,
  "DCS": 2,
  "TOWER": 65,
  "RAISING": 8,
  "BREAKOUT": 6,
};

var newList = {};
Object.keys(list).sort(function(a,b){return list[a]-list[b]})
                 .map(key => newList[key] = list[key]);
console.log(newList);
```

Comment: We finally saw that this is what OP meant. I would have done something like this too. The purist will say you cannot rely on the order in a key-value object

Comment: The OP updated his question. I was able to get his expected result. I am not sure what your issue is.

Comment: No issue. I voted up and applauded. But as I said, [some people here will argue that one cannot rely on the order in a hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520228/how-to-sort-an-objects-by-its-values-with-multiple-keys/55520586#comment97745427_55520228)

Comment: Perhaps the map is a bit misleading because you use a side effect. A [forEach is more appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55520586/295783) in my opinion but still you were the first to guess/solve what OP wanted

Answer (score 2):

Object.entries and a forEach since map is not the most relevant method to copy key-values

and as [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520228/how-to-sort-an-objects-by-its-values-with-multiple-keys/55520586#comment97745427_55520228) mentioned, you are better off with an actual array since you should not rely on key order in an object

```js
const list = {
  "CYLINDER": 2986,
  "HYDRAULIC": 1421,
  "JACKS": 84,
  "INSTALLATION": 119,
  "REAR": 61,
  "JACK": 334,
  "TUBE": 1,
  "FEED": 114,
  "ASSEMBLY": 326,
  "DCS": 2,
  "TOWER": 65,
  "RAISING": 8,
  "BREAKOUT": 6,
},newList = {}

Object.entries(list).sort((a,b) => a[1]-b[1])
  .forEach(elm => newList[elm[0]] = elm[1])

console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te first thing you'll need to do is turn your objects properties into an array, something in the form

```
[
   {word: "CYLINDER", count: 2986},
   {word: "HYDRAULIC", count: 4421}
   // etc
]
```

Then you can use sort.

```js
var input = {
  "CYLINDER": 2986,
  "HYDRAULIC": 1421,
  "JACKS": 84,
  "INSTALLATION": 119,
  "REAR": 61,
  "JACK": 334,
  "TUBE": 1,
  "FEED": 114,
  "ASSEMBLY": 326,
  "DCS": 2,
  "TOWER": 65,
  "RAISING": 8,
  "BREAKOUT": 6,
};

var result = Object.keys(input)
                   .map( x => ({word:x, count:input[x]}))
                   .sort( (a,b) => a.count - b.count);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you're changing the structure then you could also use `Object.entries()` and strip the `.map()` call: `Object.entries(input).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])`

Comment: @Andreas but then you lose the key which is needed for the result... unless im missing something.

Comment: `Object.entries()` returns: `[ [key, value], [key, value], ... ]`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the doc you linked, the `sort` function accepts an argument, that is the compareFunction. So, if you want to sort an array of object by their `INSTALLATION` key, you can simply do:

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {return a.INSTALLATION - b.INSTALLATION})
```

Comment: Values. I bet he means Sort from 1 to 2986

Answer (score 0):

Combine `Object.keys(obj)`, `.sort()` & `.map`

```js
const obj = {
  "CYLINDER": 2986,
  "HYDRAULIC": 1421,
  "JACKS": 84,
  "INSTALLATION": 119,
  "REAR": 61,
  "JACK": 334,
  "TUBE": 1,
  "FEED": 114,
  "ASSEMBLY": 326,
  "DCS": 2,
  "TOWER": 65,
  "RAISING": 8,
  "BREAKOUT": 6,
}

var sorted = {};

console.log("Un-sorted", obj);

Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key){
  sorted[key] = obj[key];
});

console.log("Sorted", sorted)
```

Im sure there is a more elegant solution, but this works too.

Comment: That sorts by key name, not value